# Maven Multi-Module - Jacoco report aggregation

Tags: maven, code-coverage, jacoco, multi-module

I have a multi-module maven projects. A module `services` with a big and growing number of child modules `child-a`, ... , `child-n`. These children also have a dependency on a `common` modules. I want to find a simple way to generate an aggregated report (in the xml and csv format) with Jacoco (or other simple maven-compatible tool) in my CI (Github Actions)

This seems like a simple enough use case and yet I can't find any way to do this. What I've stumbled onto so far is:

1. `jacoco:merge`: Can only merge .exec files and then we need source and classes to generate an xml or csv report.
2. `jacoco:report-aggregate`: Need to have a module with a dependency on all modules (which in my case is highly non-practical and will not respond dynamically to the growth in number of modules since each dependency entry must be added manually, as I haven't found a way to add all children of a `services` as dependency by only setting one dependency)

The best solution I have so far that would be to create a script which accepts an array of all the children of `services` and merges all the files with `jacococli report`. But this solutions still requires to have access to the child's classes, sources AND child's dependencies' classes and sources, which is also highly impractical.

What would be a better solution in my case ?

Thanks.